# How to replace specific range of text with other text or label in VSCode API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Some kinds of text are in an encoded form, I want to convert them all to UTF8 form.
Such as convert `"%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95"` to `"测试"` but also do not change the file, meaning `"%E6%B5%8B%E8%AF%95"` is displayed as `"测试"` until I edit it.

Is there a way to do that?

I tried `activeEditor.setDecorations()`, but it can only change the style and also cannot *hide* the original text. I also tried `HoverProvider` - it helps, but it's not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible by using decorations (at least now in 1.52.1).

We can add text with the `before` or `after` properties.

And we can hide the original text by setting its `opacity` to `0` and by abusing `letterSpacing` with a negative value to reduce its effective width to 0.

```js
const replacementDecoration = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
        opacity: '0',
        letterSpacing: '-100px',
        before: {
            contentText: 'test',
        }
    })
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions